# How to divide load between different processors

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, intel, tbb

I am running some parallel code on a machine which has 4 intel processors and 8 cores on each .I am using TBB.Suppose a given loop(that I parallelize ) has X iterations  how should I choose my grainsize to ensure the load is evenly divided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have N equally powerful CPUs.

If there are no loop carried dependencies (e.g, nothing in iteration i is used by following iterations), then you can simply run loop iterations 0..X/N on CPU 1, and iterations (X/N)+1..(2*X/N) on CPU 2, etc, assuming that each iteration takes exactly the same amount of time, or at least an average amount of that doesn't vary wildly.

If there *are* loop carried
dependencies, you may have a problem if iteration i depends on all previous iterations.  If it only dependes on the the previous k iterations, you can have CPU1 do iterations 0..X/N, and CPU2 do iterations X/N-k..(2*X/N), wasting some work but allowing CPU2 to collect the results it needs, etc. for all processors.

If iterations take wildly varying amounts of time, you're better off setting up a worklist containing the iterations,
and have the CPUs grab iterations from the workslist as they complete previous iterations.  This way the work is divided up as demand appears. You have to be sure that the time per unit of work grabbed  is lots larger than the effort to get the work, or you'll get no parallel advantage; one way to do this is to grab a small range of iterations from the worklist, such that the total work in the range exceeds the scheduling overhead significantly.

Comment: the iterations are completely independent of each other.What makes you say X/2?I do X/4(coz 4 processors?) but that doesnt seem to quite give me the speedup I desired.Also how can I utilize the fact that there are 8 cores on each of these 4 processors.

Comment: @Manish: I misread your question; I thought you only had 2 CPUs. If you have N CPUs, you obviously want to divide the work into N roughlyl equal sized parts. The rest of my answer is all detail driven by what it takes to divide things in N equal parts; I revised the answer to use .../N instead of .../2

Comment: Thanks.And do the cores also play any part? I believe TBB takes cares of the cores available automatically and thats a parameter user cannot tune?

Comment: @Manish: I don't know specifically about TBB, but most paralell execution engines provide you with some means to indicate how many physical CPUs you should use.  You'll have to check the TBB docs.  If you don't know how many cores to use, I'd switch to the single-queue scheme, which works no matter how many CPUs you have.

Answer (score 0):

With TBB, you don't have to select a grain size for parallel_for. In most cases, TBB will dynamically load balance the work pretty well by default. The answer of Ira Baxter correctly describes how you should partition the work across a pool of threads; but TBB already has similar mechanisms in place that do this for you.

ADDED: Surely manual work partitioning might get better results in complex cases. Though in this case one would likely need to use TBB tasks, as parallel_for might not provide enough control; for example, in general it is not possible to specify the exact size of a per-thread chunk.

Comment: So are you saying that the TBB library would be automatically aware of my 4 processors and 8 cores on each(in this case)? I change the grainsize dynamically depending on the number of iterations and it does perform better than having just auto_partitioner w/o any grainsize.What I am not sure is if I have received the max performance.Any tools to check for the same?

Comment: @Manish: do you have reasons to think that better performance is possible? Have you done a performance or scalability study? As for performance analysis tools, Intel(R) VTune Amplifier XE is probably the best tool for a TBB application, because it is aware of some TBB constructs and can present information in a more meaningful way. And its timeline view is good for load balance visualization.

Comment: How does TBB know about loop carried dependencies? About uneven execution rates for iterations?  I believe it might handle the no-loop-carried dependencies, roughly equal size iterations by itself as it is pretty trivial to divide by N.

Comment: @Ira Baxter: My response was about load balancing. TBB does not know about dependencies, you are right.  As for uneven execution rates, TBB balances the work dynamically via work stealing, and so able to cope with imbalance.